# Holomorphic differentials on $\mathbb{P^1}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, projective-space, holomorphic-functions

I'm studying "*The Arithmetic of Elliptic curves* by **J. H. Silverman**". The author has shown in example 4.5 (page 32), that we have not any holomorphic differentials on $\mathbb{P^1}$. I don't understand the term "*holomorphic*" for differentials. I've seen some definitions for holomorphic functions, but what does it mean for a differential? For instance, in the above example, I cannot understand how $div(dt)=-2(\infty)$? where "$t$" is a coordinate function on $\mathbb{P^1}$. 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure how Silverman defines the differentials, but to check the order at infinity you want to check the order of $dt/du$ where $u$ is a uniformizer for the point at infinity, for example $u=1/t$.

Answer (score 1):

Any $\omega\in\Omega_C$ is *holomorphic* if $\operatorname{ord}_P(g)\geq0$ for all $P\in C$, where $\omega=g\,dt$ and $t$ is a uniformizer at $P$. Note that $g\in\bar{K}(C)$.

**Explanation:**

On page 31 in Proposition 4.3(a) it is stated that

> For every $\omega\in\Omega_C$ there exists a unique function $g\in\bar{K}(C)$, depending on $\omega$ and $t$, satisfying $$\omega=g\,dt.$$
>   We denote $g$ by $\omega/dt$.

Then on the same page in Proposition 4.3(c) it is stated that

> The quantity $$\operatorname{ord}_P(\omega/dt)$$ depends only on $\omega$ and $P$, independent of the choice of uniformizer $t$. We call this value the *order of $\omega$* at $P$ and denote it by $\operatorname{ord}_P(\omega)$.

On page 32 there is the definition

> The differential $\omega\in\Omega_C$ is *regular* (or *holomorphic*) if $$\operatorname{ord}_P(\omega)\geq0\quad\text{for all }P\in C.$$